# How to import query in Access Database?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an access database and I would like to import a query from another database using VBA. However I bump into the following message

[image]

Here is my code:

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "Microsoft Access", FileAdress, acQuery, "RawData", "RawData Imported"
```

This code says the Table or Query RawData is not available. The problem is I'm sure it exists in the source database.

The FileAdress is also ok. when I change the code to import a table it works (TableName, acTable...)

Does anyone know how to make it work please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't link queries, only import them.

Use

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "Microsoft Access", FileAdress, acQuery, "RawData", "RawData Imported"
```